# Meteor 0.7.2 + OplogObserveDriver not updating under certain circumstances

Tags: meteor

This is pretty cutting-edge as 0.7.2 was just released today, but I thought I'd ask in case somebody can shed some light.

I didn't report this to MDG because I can't reproduce this on my dev environment and thus I wouldn't have a recipe to give them.

I've set up oplog tailing in my production environment, which was deployed exactly as my dev environment was, except it's on a remote server.

The server runs Ubuntu + node 0.10.26 and I'm running the bundled version of the app with forever. Mongo reports its replSet is working in order.

The problem is that some collection updates made in server code don't make it to the client. This is the workflow the code is following:

1. Server publishes the collection using a very simple user_id: this.userId selector.
2. Client subscribes
3. Client calls a server method using Meteor.call()
4. Client starts observing a query on that collection using a specific _id: "something" selector. It will echo on "changed"
5. Server method calls .update() on the document matching that "something" _id, after doing some work.

If I run the app without oplog tailing (by not setting MONGO_OPLOG_URL), the above workflow works every time. However, if I run it with oplog tailing, the client doesn't echo any changes and if I query the collection directly from the JS console on the browser I don't see the updated version of the collection.

To add to the mystery, if I go into the mongo console and update the document manually, I see the the change on the client immediately. Or if I refresh the browser after the Meteor.call() and then query the collection manually from the js console the changes are there, as I'd expect.

As mentioned before, if I run the app on my dev environment with oplog tailing (verified using the facts package) it all works as expected and I can't reproduce the issue. The only difference here would be latency between client and server? (my dev environment is in my LAN).

Maybe if somebody is running into something similar we can isolate the issue and make it reproducible..

Comment: The changes are definitely getting from your app into the database? This is surprising, and if you can make it something we can reproduce or debug I'd love to know.

Comment: and it never happens with 0.7.1?

Comment: @DavidGlasser absolutely. The .update() is called server-side and I can see the changes in mongo, however the client doesn't see them until I refresh or change something else in mongo. I will try to come up with a recipe.

Comment: @imslavko This did not happen with 0.7.1

Comment: I have that problem too, even i my meteor and met can't run as usually

Comment: @yozawiratama if you're experiencing this in dev mode, you should be able to reproduce it under a set of conditions and report it to the team

Comment: Oops sorry, my false. My meteor works now, i reinstall my meteor in mac. :D